# Wordpress search doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

When I write something into search box and press enter, it just refreshes with parameter ?s=searched-item (you can search only on index page). I have set up searchpage.php and made search page with searchpage.php template in administration.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try to just copy the `search.php` from twentyfifteen theme in your theme (and removing anything you've created), and trying if the search works? If you've made `searchpage.php` then the search problably won't work...

Comment: Thanks. I had to copy search.php and search-content.php, but then it worked.

Comment: Great :) You can change the layout if you want, I think that it's only important that the names are the same (of the .php files)